# Slow performance using STL in NEH algorithm

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, stl

I've got problem with NEH algorithm. I implemented it but it's veeeery slow and I can't figure out what the problem is. Could You verify what I did wrong, what causes bad performance? Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(unsigned int rowsNum, unsigned int columnsNum) :m_rows(rowsNum), m_columns(columnsNum){ resize(rowsNum, columnsNum); };
    T& operator()(unsigned int r, unsigned int c) { return m_data[r*columns() + c]; }
    const T& operator()(unsigned int r, unsigned int c) const { return m_data[r*columns() + c]; }
    unsigned int rows() const { return m_rows; }
    unsigned int columns() const { return m_columns; }
    Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& matrix) const;
private:
    void resize(unsigned int rowsNum, unsigned int colsNum);
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> m_data;
    unsigned int m_rows;
    unsigned int m_columns;
};

template <typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix& matrix) const
{

}

template <typename T>
void Matrix<T>::resize(unsigned int rowsNum, unsigned int colsNum)
{
    m_rows = rowsNum;
    m_columns = colsNum;
    m_data.reset(new T[rowsNum*colsNum]);
}

class Task
{
public:
    Task(unsigned int ordNum = 0) :m_ordNum(ordNum) { }
    unsigned int readFromFile(std::istream& is);
    unsigned int totalTasksTime() const;
    unsigned int ordNum() const { return m_ordNum; }
    unsigned int machinesNum() const { return m_params.size(); }
    unsigned int machineTaskTime(unsigned int machineNum) const { return m_params[machineNum - 1]; }
protected:
    std::vector<unsigned int> m_params;
    unsigned int m_ordNum;
    unsigned int m_totalTasksTime;
};


unsigned int Task::totalTasksTime() const
{
    return m_totalTasksTime;
}

unsigned int Task::readFromFile(std::istream& is)
{
    std::string line;
    while (is.peek() == '\n') // omija puste linie
        is.get();

    std::getline(is, line);

    m_params.clear();

    std::istringstream istr(line);
    unsigned int i = 1;
    while (istr)
    {
        int taskNum, taskTime;
        istr >> taskNum >> taskTime;
        if (istr)
        {
            if (i == m_params.size() + 1)
                m_params.push_back(taskTime);
            else
                throw "Zly numer indesku maszyny - musza być po kolei";

            i++;
        }
    }
    m_totalTasksTime = std::accumulate(m_params.begin(), m_params.end(), 0);
    return m_params.size();
}


class Instance
{
public:
    Instance() { }
    Instance(const std::string& name) :m_name(name) { }
    void readFromFile(std::istream& is);
    const std::string& name() const { return m_name; }
    void name(std::string& newName) { m_name = newName; }
    void neh(std::list<unsigned int>& permutation, unsigned int &totalTime) const;
    const Task* getTask(unsigned int taskNum) const { return &m_tasks[taskNum]; }
private:
    unsigned int calculateTotalTime(const std::list<unsigned int>& permutationList, unsigned int bestTimeFound) const;
    std::vector<Task> m_tasks;
    std::string m_name;
};


typedef std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> MapIterator;
typedef std::vector<Task>::const_iterator TaskVecIterator;

bool compareTasksPtrBySumTime(const Task* t1, const Task* t2)
{
    unsigned int t1TotalTime = t1->totalTasksTime(), t2TotalTime = t2->totalTasksTime();

    bool w1 = t1TotalTime < t2TotalTime, w2 = t1TotalTime == t2TotalTime && t1->ordNum() > t2->ordNum();

    return w1 || w2;
}

void Instance::neh(std::list<unsigned int>& permutation, unsigned int &totalTime) const
{
    // sortowanie zadań po całkowitym czasie wykonania 
    std::list<const Task*> sortedTaskList;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_tasks.size(); i++)
        sortedTaskList.push_back(&m_tasks[i]);

    sortedTaskList.sort(compareTasksPtrBySumTime);

    while (!sortedTaskList.empty()) // 
    {
        const Task* taskPtr = sortedTaskList.back(); sortedTaskList.pop_back();
        unsigned int taskNum = taskPtr->ordNum();

        std::list<unsigned int>::iterator bestPosition = permutation.begin();
        unsigned int bestTotalTime = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
        permutation.push_front(taskNum);
        for (std::list<unsigned int>::iterator it = permutation.begin(); // szukanie najlepszej pozycji
             it != permutation.end(); it++)
          {
            unsigned int currentTotalTime = calculateTotalTime(permutation, bestTotalTime);

            if (bestTotalTime > currentTotalTime)
              {
            bestTotalTime = currentTotalTime;
            bestPosition = it;
              }
            auto nextIt = it; nextIt++;
            if (nextIt != permutation.end())
              std::swap(*it, *nextIt);
          }

        totalTime = bestTotalTime;
        permutation.insert(bestPosition, taskNum);
        permutation.pop_back();

    }
    std::cout << "Ukonczono:" << name() << std::endl;
}

unsigned int Instance::calculateTotalTime(const std::list<unsigned int>& permutationList, unsigned int bestTimeFound) const
{
    unsigned int rows = m_tasks[*permutationList.begin() - 1].machinesNum() + 1, columns = permutationList.size() + 1;
    Matrix<unsigned int> matrix(rows, columns);
    unsigned int totalTime = 0;

    for (unsigned int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
        matrix(0, c) = 0;

    for (unsigned int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        matrix(r, 0) = 0;

    std::list<unsigned int>::const_iterator it = permutationList.begin();
    for (unsigned int c = 1; c < columns; c++)
    {
        unsigned int taskNum = *it;
        for (unsigned int r = 1; r < rows; r++)
            (matrix(r, c) = std::max(matrix(r, c - 1), matrix(r - 1, c)) + m_tasks[taskNum - 1].machineTaskTime(r));// >bestTimeFound;
        //  return std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();

        it++;
    }

    return matrix(rows - 1, columns - 1);

}

void Instance::readFromFile(std::istream& is)
{
    int taskNum, machineNum;

    is >> taskNum >> machineNum;

    for (int i = 0; i < taskNum; i++)
    {
        Task task(i + 1);
        task.readFromFile(is);
        if (is)
            m_tasks.push_back(task);
    }
}


class InstanceVector
{
public:
    void readFromFile(std::istream& is);
    void neh(std::list< std::list<unsigned int> >& result) const;
    void neh(std::ostream& os) const;
private:
    std::vector<Instance> m_instances;
};

void InstanceVector::readFromFile(std::istream& is)
{
    while (is)
    {
        std::string name;
        is >> name;
        Instance instance(name);
        instance.readFromFile(is);
        std::list<unsigned int> l;
        unsigned int totalTime;
        if (is)
          m_instances.push_back(instance);
    }
}


void InstanceVector::neh(std::list< std::list<unsigned int> >& results) const
{
    std::vector<Instance>::const_iterator it;
    for (it = m_instances.begin(); it != m_instances.end(); it++)
    {
        std::list<unsigned int> resultInstance;
        unsigned int totalTimeInstance;
        it->neh(resultInstance, totalTimeInstance);
        results.push_back(resultInstance);
    }
}

void InstanceVector::neh(std::ostream& os) const
{
    std::list< std::list<unsigned int> > results;
    for (std::vector<Instance>::const_iterator it = m_instances.begin();
        it != m_instances.end(); it++)
    {
        std::list<unsigned int> resultInstance;
        unsigned int totalTimeInstance;
        it->neh(resultInstance, totalTimeInstance);
        results.push_back(std::move(resultInstance));
    }

    for (std::list< std::list<unsigned int> >::const_iterator it = results.begin();
        it != results.end(); it++)
    {
        for (std::list<unsigned int>::const_iterator itPermutation = it->begin(); itPermutation != it->end(); itPermutation++)
            os << *itPermutation << " ";
        os << std::endl;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    InstanceVector instanceVec;
    std::ifstream input("bench_fs.txt");
    if (input.is_open())
        instanceVec.readFromFile(input);

    std::ofstream output("output.txt");
    instanceVec.neh(output);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: `I implemented it but it's veeeery slow and I can't figure out what the problem is`  Are you running a debug (unoptimized) build or a release (optimized) build?  If it's a debug build, don't bother asking about slowness.  Time release builds.

Comment: I used release mode. I compiled it in Visual Studio 2013 and Linux gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: `m_data.reset(new T[rowsNum*colsNum]);`  Your `resize` function is highly inefficient, especially if the number of entries is less than the current number of entries.  You're going to the allocator over and over again.  Why not just use `std::vector` and call `resize()` on the vector?  Why go the `unique_ptr` route when you could have easily just done `std::vector<T>` as the container?  Other than this, why not profile your code?

Answer (score 0):

The time taken by your program dependent both on the code and the data. Without the data we can only guess at why your program is taking more time than you expected. I will hazard some guesses as to where time is being lost but first I will strongly encourage you to try measuring how your program is spending its time. On Linux you can use perf to measure where your program is spending its time but there are plenty of tools to chose from. This will help in two ways. First, the following guesses may be completely wrong. Second, you will know how to find the performance problems in your next program.

In the absence of any hard information my gut is wary of two elements of your program.

1. You are storing your permutation as a std::list and I suspect that traversal and modification of this list is taking more time than you are saving by having an efficient push_front(). Try switching to std::vector. You can avoid push_front() by doing a push_back() and reversing the direction you move the new task through the permutation and keeping a best permutation rather than best position.
2. Inside calculateTotalTime() the matrix object is allocating and deallocating memory each time. This is potentially adding up to a significant amount of time. You could pass the matrix as an argument to calculateTotalTime() and store the matrix object at a level where it will be allocated/deallocated far less frequently. You probably need to do as @PaulMcKenzie suggests and use std::vector in your matrix class, rather than unique_ptr, so that you can reserve capacity ahead of time.

Hope that helps.